# Invalid time on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, date, timezone, clock

## Problem

My FreeBSD is always 2 hours behind when I'm offline although my BIOS clock shows the UTC time and my time zone is set to CET in /etc/localtime.

I'd like FreeBSD to look at the clock in BIOS, assume that it is UTC, check what time zone is chosen and then set the time on the machine accordingly.

---

## Details

I've already tried removing `/etc/wall_cmos_clock` and running `adjkerntz -a` after I changed `machdep.adjkerntz` with `sysctl` from `-7200` to `0`. I rebooted the machine several times in different configurations during that process.

I am not interested in solutions utilizing the ntpd utility as it requires an Internet connection.

It is a dual boot system. The second system is Ubuntu 17.04 and it is its GRUB which boots FreeBSD via chain loading.

### Workaround

I couldn't find any solutions online so I decided to change the time manually with `date(1)`.

```
# date +%H%M
1426
# date 1626
```

I'd love to know if there is a better solution however.

---

#### References

- [Wrong time but right timezone](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/56345/) @ the FreeBSD Forums.
- [Daylight saving time - how time is stored, how to change it](http://www.freebsddiary.org/daylight.php) @ the FreeBSD Diary.

Answer (score 1):

To have your correct time, please instead of CET, set your locatime to `Europe/Warsaw`.

To do it in FreeBSD, run as root:

```
ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Warsaw /etc/localtime
```

Comment: Didn't help. I've tried that already... the system was still two hours behind the expected time.

Comment: It it a dual boot system? It is not coincidence it is two hours.

Comment: it is. The 2nd system is Ubuntu 17.04. Does it matter if the clock in BIOS shows the UTC time?